Postgres Testcontainers for Golang: WithInitScripts with multiple scripts does not work
Setting up the test like this:
postgresContainer, err := postgres.RunContainer(ctx,
        testcontainers.WithImage("docker.io/postgres:16-alpine"),
        postgres.WithDatabase(dbName),
        postgres.WithUsername(dbUser),
        postgres.WithPassword(dbPassword),
        postgres.WithInitScripts(filepath.Join("..", "postgres_migrations", "v1_create_bands.sql"),
            filepath.Join("..", "tests", "postgres_scripts", "bands_init.sql")),
        testcontainers.WithWaitStrategy(
            wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections").
                WithOccurrence(2).
                WithStartupTimeout(5*time.Second)),
    )

v1_create_bands.sql:
CREATE TABLE bands (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

bands_init.sql:
INSERT INTO bands(id, name) VALUES 
(1, 'Band1'),
(2, 'Band2');

When I run the test I get the error relation "bands" does not exist at character 13 while trying to run bands_init.sql.
But if I copy the CREATE TABLE statement into bands_init.sql I get the error relation "bands" already exists!
If I leave only bands_init.sql as the only script with 2 statements then the test passes correctly. I don't understand what is going on here.

It is not acceptable to add SOLVED to the post title. If you've found a solution, you can accept the answer that gave it to you (even if it's your own answer - see Can I answer my own question? for details). I've rolled back your edit.

The part I missed is that the error in the second scenario was while running v1_create_bands.sql. So the scripts are simply executed in alphabetical order, not in the order of passing them to the function. I renamed bands_init.sql so that it is alphabetically greater than v1_create_bands.sql, and then the test passed.

Indeed, Testcontainers API just copies the given files to the Postgres' well-known init location. And once there, it's Postgres the one taking the files in the alphabetical order.
I think letting testcontainers libs copy the files into the folder renaming them with a name in the order they were passed would be a bad idea (testcontainers-go maintainer here) because I'd expect developers have the same file name in the testdata folder than in the production (or at least represent production the closest)

It's not very convenient keeping them in the lexicographical order though. I have to use numbers and add letters like x/y/z, because 10 is less than 2 lexicographically. Other test frameworks allow listing script files in the exact order they should be executed.

Well, I think we are open to any discussion on this feature request: "support for renaming copied files in the order they were passed" :) And adding references to those test frameworks would support the request
